# Theoretical modelling of a mechanical experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, models

For my lab class I was doing an experiment on one of the mirror of the Virgo interferometer. After me and my colleagues collected the data we got some meaningful result but i wanted to try and make up a toy model which would explain the expected result so to compare it with the one we got, which actually contains a subtlety.

The experiment is the following: the mirror is encapsulated in a vacuum chamber of which we can choose the specific vacuum pressure. Then one of the mirror resonance modes is excited with the help of a function generator and some coils. What we measure, after shutting down the external exciting force, is the time with which the oscillation decay so to evaluate the Q-factor of the system. We do this for many different air pressures and plot the results.

What i would actually like to model is the dependence of the time decay constant on pressure. The model I had in mind was a simple Newtonian problem where the dumping force is given by the drag of the air $$F_d = \frac{1}{2}\rho\dot{x}^2C_dA$$ and the dependence on the pressure is given, supposing that the ideal gas law holds, by $$\rho = \frac{P}{R_{\text{specific}}T}$$ To simplify the problem $C_d, A, R_{\text{specific}}, T, m$ and the amplitude of the initial external force, are considered constants.

Given all this, I don't know how to build up the problem since what I tried, failed and I'm not sure how to implement the initial dependence on the external oscillatory force. To make it clear, I'm only interested on the behaviour after the external force is shut down.

What I would expect is a dependence, not strictly linear, $\tau(P)$ such that whenever the pressure increases $\tau$ decreases and viceversa such that the amplitude of the oscillation dies out as $$A(t) = A_0\exp\left(-\frac{t}{\tau(P)}\right)+\text{possible other terms}$$

What would you do? What simulated results could you bring up? Would it be possible to build up an analytic solution with some dependence on some parameters so to do a parametric fitting on our data?

Comment: Note that in that kind of equipment the $Q$ is also limited by the inelasticity of the mirror suspension due to metal creep and stick-sleep (these are the phenomena which ultimately limit the $Q$ of the system). So, for a realistic model, you may have to consider also these phenomena. As a first approximation, you can calculate the overall $Q$ as $1/Q = 1/Q_\mathrm{internal}+1/Q_\mathrm{pressure}$, where $Q_\mathrm{internal}$ is the factor due to creep and stick-sleep.

Comment: Note also that at very low pressure the drag force is no longer proportional to the speed squared but just to the speed.

Comment: Oops, indeed in the above is not _stick-sleep_ (ronf...) but _stick-slip_.

Comment: This is the kind of question were data really helps move the model forward.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Ok, I didn't know that the drag changes at low pressures, maybe this can be implemented as well, but really I'm interested on a very simplified model!

Comment: @JEB Yeah, probably would. But what i would like is just a theoretical model, the experimental background is just to give some background information on the problem. At the end what i would like is a model which describes a certain situation, be it related to some measurements or not